# Website integration with Amazon Associates

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I'm trying to integrate my Drupal website with my Amazon Associates store.

The goal is to:

1. Manage inventory on Amazon
2. Website syncs data with Amazon API for inventory status
3. Manage orders on Amazon
4. Keep my Drupal website design

So, steps for visitor are:

1. User enters my Drupal website (my design)
2. Adds any product to cart (my design)
3. Checkout his cart on Amazon (Amazon design)

I would appreciate if someone points which of the Amazon API I should use to:

- Sync inventory status
- Create cart on my website and checkout it on Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it's exactly the sort of use-case the [Amazon aStore](http://astore.amazon.com/) exists for. It can be as out-of-the-box or customizable as you want it to be. It's pretty much hosting an Amazon Store and cart on your own website through the associates program.

You can use custom CSS as well and this is explained in [this help page](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/tips/t18).